# Having trouble installing pygame ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pygame

I'm having a lot of trouble installing pygame. I'm running ubuntu. I'm trying to install it with 'pip install pygame' but I keep getting an error message:

```
     Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
```

I've tried downloading the source from the pygame website but still its not working i just get the same error when i try and run setup.py.

Any Ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have SDL installed? check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/344512/what-is-the-general-procedure-to-install-development-libraries-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install Pygame on Ubuntu is through `apt`. Just run `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`, and it will handle all the native dependencies for you. `pip` is better for pure-python dependencies or if you *have* to use it (eg, in a virtualenv).

Comment: I did and it was installed, now how do I use this install on Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

If u got error like 404 Not Found when run 
 `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`

Then this link can help you
https://community.webfaction.com/questions/315/how-do-i-install-pygame

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
cd /usr/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```

and finally run the pip command (can be done through virtualenv or conda):

```
pip install 'Pygame == 1.9.1release' --allow-external Pygame --allow-unverified Pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

In *pycharm* specifying a dev version (in my case 2.0.0.dev8) fixed that problem for me.
Here's the after:

[image]